# Independent increments vs independent events

Tags: stochastic-processes, independence, poisson-process

I am considering a counting stochastic process which has independent increments (just like a Poisson process).

We know that a Poisson process has independent increments. Furthermore, one of the assumptions is that the events being counted are independent of each other (since the number of events occurring between any two times is assumed to follow a Poisson distribution, which implies independence of events).

I was wondering whether the property of independent increments for a stochastic counting process (in general) also implies that the events being counted are independent of each other? I understand that the converse is true, but I am interested in the forward direction.

Thank you

Comment: Independent increments means that the number of events in any two disjoint intervals are independent. What do you mean by independent events of the Poisson process?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification.When I say two events are independent, I mean that the occurrence of one event doesn't affect the probability of another. So if A and B are independent events, P (A)=P (A | B)

Comment: Yes, but what events specifically are you asking about in this context? The independent increments means that ${N(t_2)-N(t_1)}$ and ${N(t_4)-N(t_3)}$ are independent for $t_1<t_2<t_3<t_4$. What events are you asking if this implies independence for?

Comment: A counting process {N (t)} is one where N (t) represents the number of events that had occurred up to time t. So for instance, if the counting process was a measure of the number of insurance claims which had occurred, an event would be a claim occurring

Comment: "A claim occurring" is not a well defined event (in the probabilistic meaning). For example, "a claim occurring before time $t$" is an event, and it is independent of events such as "10 claims occurred during $[s,u]$" where $s>t$, but not independent of the event if $s<t$. Are you perhaps thinking of the independence of the time between claims?

Comment: I believe in common literature we say that events being modelled by a Poisson distribution are assumed to be independent (occurrence doesn't affect another). If we consider a homogeneous Poisson process, the number of events between (s,s+t) occurring follows a Poisson distribution with rate rt. Thus, doesn't it make sense to say that events in the Poisson process are independent? Is this meaning of events being independent not something which can be generalized?

Comment: I think the source of you confusion is that the "events" of the Poisson counting process are just a description of the model but not events in the probabilistic sense, so it is meaningless to say that they are independent. Only when you add time you can talk about events, and then the independent increments are defined in my previous comments. This is more general than a Poisson process (the increments may not be distributed Poisson).

Comment: Is it maybe compound Poisson processes you have in mind? Here we have claim numbers given by a Poisson process $N$ independent of iid claim sizes $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. The total claim amount $t$ is $Y(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)} X_i$. Here (a) the inter-arrival times between claims are independent because the Poisson process has independent increments, and (b) the event types (claim-sizes) are independent because $(X_1,\ldots)$ were assumed to be mutually independent. Extensions are easily possible. $N$ need not be a Poisson process, and the claim-sizes need to be identically distributed.